# Recognizer.read('trainer/trainer.yml) could not find trainer.yml file

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to run this code but it did not because I am not able to download this file from GitHub. Is there anyone who knows how I can download this file?

This is the link to the file with the filename `face-trainner.yml`: [https://github.com/codingforentrepreneurs/OpenCV-Python-Series/tree/…](https://github.com/codingforentrepreneurs/OpenCV-Python-Series/tree/%E2%80%A6)

I'm getting this error when running my program:

```
error: OpenCV(4.4.0) C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-ckfq0tq7\opencv_contrib\modules\face\src\facerec.cpp:61: error: (-2:Unspecified error) File can't be opened for reading! in function 'cv::face::FaceRecognizer::read'
```

Comment: Do you have the file downloaded called `face-trainner.yml`?

Comment: Unfortunately, I could not. I've this link to downaload but it did not work.                          https://github.com/codingforentrepreneurs/OpenCV-Python-Series/tree/master/src/recognizers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the main section of the GitHub repository: [https://github.com/codingforentrepreneurs/OpenCV-Python-Series](https://github.com/codingforentrepreneurs/OpenCV-Python-Series/)

1. Press the code button and then download as zip
2. Unzip the file in your downloads
3. Navigate to `src/recognisers` and the file `face-trainner.yml` should be there
4. Use that file how you want in your project (discard of the rest if you have no need for it)

Also make sure that you have typed the correct file name in your program with the two 'n's (`face-trainner.yml` not `face-trainer.yml`)

Comment: I DID IT. THANK YOU SO MUCH. IT MEANS A LOT ! :')

Comment: @elifozcan97 No problem. BTW, would you mind accepting my answer? Cheers.

Comment: File "C:\Users\EMRE\OpenCV-Python-Series-master\src\faces.py", line 54, in <module>
    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)

error: OpenCV(4.4.0) C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-ckfq0tq7\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:651: error: (-2:Unspecified error) The function is not implemented. Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Cocoa support. If you are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then re-run cmake or configure script in function 'cvShowImage'  DO U HAVE ANY SOLUTION FOR THIS ERROR ? Thx

Comment: Actually I did these commands... unfortunately still getting same error :(